# DB2 function accepting rows

Tags: db2, stored-functions

I have a function which is accepting an id from type varchar. The id represents the pk. But sometimes the pk consists more of two parameters. So is it possible to make the function more generic and asking for the type inside the function. The input parameter should be the object(row) from which the id should be taken.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CHECK_VALID"
(ID VARCHAR(8))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL23562233244578
RETURN
ID IS ...
```

Comment: Very vague description... "The id represents the pk" of what table? Could you provide some use case description and complete example helping us to understand what you try to achieve at all?

Comment: You may use XML data type to pass composite PK values, if you are lazy to use the corresponding number of parameters, and you check row existence in a table with static name like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IBZI_XTY).

Comment: You can overload the function if that is what you are looking for: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_VALID (ID1 VARCHAR(8), ID2 VARCHAR(8))...`. Also, don't quote identifiers unless you really need to, if you really need to, concider changing the identifier.